# Error when using DMatrix (nalgebra) in train_test_split function of smartcore in rust

Tags: machine-learning, rust, nalgebra, smartcore

I am trying to create a small machine learning application. I am reading data from a csv and I have converted it into a DMatrix from the nalgebra library. To split the dataset into the training and test subset I would like to take advantage of the smartcore function `train_test_split`.

I am having problems when using this function with the DMatrix generated from the csv. Could you tell me why they happen and how I could solve them?

Here is the code:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::fs::File;
use nalgebra::DMatrix;
use std::str::FromStr;

use smartcore::model_selection::train_test_split;

fn read_csv(input: &mut dyn BufRead) -> Result<DMatrix<f64>, Box<dyn Error>> {

    let mut samples = Vec::new();

    let mut rows = 0;

    for line in input.lines().skip(1){
        rows += 1;

        for data in line?.split_terminator(",") {

            let a = f64::from_str(data.trim());

            match a {
                Ok(value) => samples.push(value),
                Err(e) => println!("Error parsing data in row: {}", rows),
            }
        }
    }

    let cols = samples.len() / rows;

    Ok(DMatrix::from_row_slice(rows, cols, &samples[..]))

}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

    //Load CSV
    let file = File::open("dataset/heart.csv").unwrap();
    let data: DMatrix<f64> = read_csv(&mut BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();

    let x = data.columns(0, 13).into_owned();
    let y = data.column(13).into_owned();

    // ERROR
    let (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(&x, &y.transpose(), 0.2, true);

    println!("{:?}", x_train);
    
    Ok(())

}
```

Here is the error I get back:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `nalgebra::Matrix<f64, Dyn, Dyn, VecStorage<f64, Dyn, Dyn>>: smartcore::linalg::Matrix<_>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:53:63
    |
53  |     let (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(&x, &y.transpose(), 0.2, true);
    |                                              ---------------- ^^ the trait `smartcore::linalg::Matrix<_>` is not implemented for `nalgebra::Matrix<f64, Dyn, Dyn, VecStorage<f64, Dyn, Dyn>>`
    |                                              |
    |                                              required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `smartcore::linalg::Matrix<T>`:
              DenseMatrix<T>
              nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<T, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic, nalgebra::base::vec_storage::VecStorage<T, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic>>
note: required by a bound in `train_test_split`

    |
133 | pub fn train_test_split<T: RealNumber, M: Matrix<T>>(
    |                                           ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `train_test_split`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `nalgebra::Matrix<f64, Dyn, Dyn, VecStorage<f64, Dyn, Dyn>>: BaseMatrix<_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:53:46
   |
53 |     let (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(&x, &y.transpose(), 0.2, true);
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BaseMatrix<_>` is not implemented for `nalgebra::Matrix<f64, Dyn, Dyn, VecStorage<f64, Dyn, Dyn>>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BaseMatrix<T>`:
             DenseMatrix<T>
             nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<T, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic, nalgebra::base::vec_storage::VecStorage<T, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic, nalgebra::base::dimension::Dynamic>>

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `logistic-regression` due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Might be a version problem, does `cargo tree` list 2 different versions of `nalgebra` in your dependencies?

Comment: When running cargo tree I find these versions of nalgebra:

--- nalgebra v0.32.3
  | --- ....
--- smartcore v0.23.2
  | --- nalgebra v0.23.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `smartcore@0.2.0` depends on `nalgebra@0.23.2` so it only implemented it's traits for `nalgebra` types of that version. Until there's an updated `smartcore` that depends on a more recent version of `nalgebra` you'll have to downgrade to that same `nalgebra` version:

```toml
[dependencies]
nalgebra = "0.23.2"
smartcore = "0.2.0"
```